# Whats the correct way to pass a username and password to soap header in web service from client app?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asmx, soap-client

A client has asked me about securing a web service. He needs me to write a test app and test it all out. So I said I would. But now I am running into an issue on protecting it.
I had tried using SOAP,

```
public AuthHeader Authentication;
[SoapHeader("Authentication", Required=true)]
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    if (Authentication.userName == "chris" && Authentication.passWord == "test")
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

The issue I am having is how do I pass the username and password to the webservice so it calls the webmethod.

I was asked to find a way to use password protection on the webservice. I know I can go into the config and set configurations for authentication, but I'm stuck figuring out how to pass the name and password to the soap header from my app.

Comment: Use HTTPS for communication when passing username and password.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Do you have any examples of how https would be used? as well is using https or soap a matter of preference or is one better than the other?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thank you and thanks for the info on asmx being legacy technology. I am just trying to find a quick turnaround for doing this, I've spent a few hours trying to figure this out and keep running into a brick wall.

Comment: If your client is looking for a secure web service, then you should be using WCF, which implements WS-Security.

Comment: Appropriate Web Service security is covered under WS-Security(User/Pass, noonce, digest, full message encryption, etc).  As the previous posted stated, WCF implements that, or you can search for an implementation if you a required to stay on asmx.

Comment: So with using WCF and the implementation of WS-Security, I will be able to pass the password and username or no? It is funny I been developing web apps for 8 years now and never had the opportunity to use webservices, until now

Comment: @Samhain, I'm not required to stick with asmx. It was something that I came across while looking to create and test a webservice. The end result is up to me on which to use, and since asmx is considered legacy then I would like to stay away from it.

Comment: @user2970223 here is an article on mdsn regarding WCF security. Good luck:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh273109(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I will look over this and thanks guys for putting me in the right direction of web services.